# How to flip a 2D gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know what is a good way to flip a 2D gameObject that will flip it's animations when a condition is met.

Comment: Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
theScale.x *= -1;
transform.localScale = theScale;

Comment: Flip in which way? Just draw it backwards, replay animation in reverse, actually spin it relative to the camera (so it looks like a piece of paper being flipped over front to back), or what?

Comment: I was thinking of flipping a character when I go left or right without having to make a whole separate animation to flip it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flipping a 2D Sprite Animation in Unity 2D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568542/flipping-a-2d-sprite-animation-in-unity-2d)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// switch the x axis by multiplying by -1
transform.localScale = new Vector3(
          transform.localScale.x * -1, 
          transform.localScale.y, 
          transform.localScale.z);
```